# Transitioning height of sibling upon :targeting sibling?

Tags: css, css-selectors, accordion

I'm trying to do a sort of accordion for my website, similar to the one on [this website](http://snag.gy), but without the toggling.

The code I'm working with is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AKQhv/1/).

I have the basic setup working, but I can't seem to get the height of the `li` to transition properly (if at all); I'd appreciate some help.

Preferably the solution would only use CSS, but I am willing to use JS/jQuery if that's the only/best way.

I have tried reading other questions on this site to fix it, but I'm either doing something wrong or the solutions didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use CSS3 transitions (works in modern browsers), but it won't be possible (someone may correct me if I'm wrong) to transition `height: 0;` to `height: 100%;` So if you don't know the actual height, one way around it is to use `max-height` instead. In this case you will need to set the `max-height` to something greater than it will ever get.

So adding something like this might be what you are looking for?

```
li {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
}

h2:target~li { /* Want to transition this */
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.0s;
       -moz-transition: max-height 1.0s;
        -ms-transition: max-height 1.0s;
         -o-transition: max-height 1.0s;
            transition: max-height 1.0s;
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AKQhv/8/)

In your case, if you want to transition the opacity property as well you can just change `transition: max-height 1.0s;` to `transition: all 1.0s;` which means that you will transition all properties.

Here's a link if you want to read about CSS3 transitions:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but must've put the transition code in the wrong place. This works perfectly.